# unable get selected date with ajax control toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with two coloumn of the gridview is date.
The type of the date is string (in database SQL Server 2008).
I use object data source to show the data to the gridview.

This the declaration of the object data source class:

```
 public class daftarproperti
{    
public string tgl_mulai { get; set; }
    public string tgl_selesai { get; set; }
}
```

This is the item template:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tanggal Mulai">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_tgl_mulai" runat="server"><%#Eval("tgl_mulai") %></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="edt_tgl_mulai" runat="server" CssClass="calender" Text='<%#Bind("tgl_mulai") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="tgl_mulai_calex" runat="server" TargetControlID="edt_tgl_mulai" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupPosition="Right" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tanggal Selesai">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_tgl_selesai" runat="server"><%#Eval("tgl_selesai") %></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="edt_tgl_selesai" runat="server" CssClass="calender" Text='<%#Bind("tgl_selesai") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="tgl_selesai_calex" runat="server" TargetControlID="edt_tgl_selesai" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupPosition="Right" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>

                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

and this is the code behind

```
 public class dalamkota_rincian_8:daftarproperti
{
    public static List<daftarproperti> AmbilJadwal(string nomorSt)
    {
        List<daftarproperti> Listjadwal = new List<daftarproperti>();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nikita_app"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("xp_generatejadwal_dalamkota8", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter paramnoSt = new SqlParameter("@nomorSt", nomorSt);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramnoSt);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                daftarproperti jadwal = new daftarproperti();
                jadwal.tugasID = (int)rdr["tugasID"];
                jadwal.nama = rdr["nama"].ToString();
                jadwal.nip = rdr["nip"].ToString();
                jadwal.gol = rdr["gol"].ToString();
                jadwal.nmperan = rdr["nmperan"].ToString();
                jadwal.tgl_mulai = rdr["tgl_mulai"].ToString();
                jadwal.tgl_selesai = rdr["tgl_selesai"].ToString();
                jadwal.jumlahhari1 = rdr["jumlahhari1"] as int? ?? default(int);
                jadwal.uangtransport100 = (decimal)rdr["uangtransport100"];
                Listjadwal.Add(jadwal);
            }
        }

        return Listjadwal;
    }

    public static int UpdateJadwal(int tugasID, string nip, string gol, int kdperan, int kdlokasi, string tgl_mulai, string tgl_selesai)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nikita_app"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("xp_modifyjadwal_dalamkota8", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter paramtugasID = new SqlParameter("@tugasID", tugasID);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramtugasID);
            SqlParameter paramnip = new SqlParameter("@nip", nip);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramnip);
            SqlParameter paramkdlokasi = new SqlParameter("@kdlokasi", kdlokasi);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramkdlokasi);
            SqlParameter paramgol = new SqlParameter("@gol", gol);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramgol);
            SqlParameter paramkdperan = new SqlParameter("@kdperan", kdperan);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramkdperan);
            SqlParameter paramtgl_mulai = new SqlParameter("@tgl_mulai", tgl_mulai);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramtgl_mulai);
            SqlParameter paramtgl_selesai = new SqlParameter("@tgl_selesai", tgl_selesai);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramtgl_selesai);
            con.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

My problem is

1. i am unable to get the selected date in ajax control toolkit date
   to my database.
2. my data type for the date is string, so when i
       get the selected item from the ajax, i should convert it first to
       string (dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: please, anyone can help me with this?